# How to reset the scale bar in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I have created a scale bar in tkinter GUI. I want to reset the scale bar when I click the button

```
def Reset():
    Spd.set(0)

rad1 = Scale(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=1, length=550, width=15, variable=Spd, sliderlength=10, from_=0, to=max(Spd_BP), tickinterval=30, font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'), command= SpdData)
rad1.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Button(self, padx=18, bd=7, font=('Helvetica', 13, 'bold'), width=7, command=Reset, text="Reset",
                  bg="#F18F49").grid(row=18, column=2, pady=12)
```

Code still not working

Comment: There are missing parts in your code, like `Spd`.  Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also what do you mean *"Code still not working"*?

Comment: Now it is working with below change 'rad1.config(variable=Spd)' @acw1668

Comment: You already set `variable=Spd` in `rad1 = Scale(...)`.